# Youtube channels.list returns empty list

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I have an Android project which has been using 
[channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
and 
[playlists.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list) 
of the Youtube V3 Data Api in order to get the user watch history.

Since yestarday I cannot get channels list for my youtube account that does not have any additional channels. I know how it sounds, but this account used to have something like a default channel that had a history playlist. 
My other accounts that have channels works unchanged.

So the error I get
[Using API explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list):

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

returns empty response:

> ```
> 200 OK
>
> Cache-Control:  private, max-age=300, must-revalidate, no-transform
> Content-Encoding:  gzip
> Content-Length:  182
> Content-Type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
> Date:  Tue, 12 Jan 2016 11:04:28 GMT
> Etag:  "oqbvhYxBE6fAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNUdA3lh-IRNmblkc"
> Expires:  Tue, 12 Jan 2016 11:04:28 GMT
> Server:  GSE
> Vary:  Origin, X-Origin
>
> {
>  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
>  "etag": "\"oqbvhYxBE6fAbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXI/f7EMN1qoSm4NUdA3lh-IRNmblkc\"",
>  "pageInfo": {
>   "totalResults": 0,
>   "resultsPerPage": 0
>  },
>  "items": [
>  ]
> }
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your account status verified here https://www.youtube.com/features ?

Comment: The account is not verified, but this is not the problem itself. Clicking "verify" redirects me to the "Create channel" window. After I create a channel the API seems to return a correct answer. Still this is a change in behaviour that happened around mid December '15 and can be clearly visible in my app analytics data. The channel created is a 'default' channel.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, I'm using the `channels.list` API endpoint to get the id/username of users that register youtube access tokens through my application. 
Some time ago youtube started returning an empty 'items' array if the user has not created any channel.

Comment: Any answer to this?  A good portion of my tokens have the same response to this endpoint.

Comment: Submitted a ticket, star to have it escalated: https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4323

Comment: moved ticket. https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=8038&q=history&sort=-opened&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary%20Opened Please star it.

Comment: I encounter the same issue with v3 API, how to solve it?